# %rowtype in nested `declare...begin...end`

Tags: postgresql

inside an anonymous block, I have nested a `declare...begin...end`. Inner block cannot "see" a temp table created in outer block. What is best way to solve, still maintaining creating of temp table inside?

The below FAILs with: `CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "inline_code_block" near line 152`

```
do
$$
declare
 xyz...
being
 create temp table x ... <depending on xyz>
...
 declare
  r x%rowtype -> FAIL
 begin
...
 end;
end;
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

It cannot to work. This error is not related to block scopes, but it is related to timing. The temp table is created in runtime, but the `x%rowtype` is evaluated in validation time (before runtime). There is very simple and robust solution in Postgres. Use `record` type:

```
declare r record;
begin
```

The variable of record type takes real composite type in assign time.

Although PL/pgSQL is similar to PL/SQL, inside it is absolutely different technology, and not all patterns from Oracle are possible or are effective. And sometimes there are different (and sometimes much more comfortable) ways.

Comment: Perfect. Works inside pgpsql also. Many thanks!